# How to use templates in STS

Tags: java, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

in netbeans when I type sout and then tab it print `System.out.print();`

How I can do this in springsource tool suite ? I create template in window -> preferences -> java -> editor ->  but I dont know how to call this template I try TAB, ENTER or ctrl space but with no success

Comment: I know I read this: http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ but when press CTRL + SPACE  there isnt my template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally it works when I restore all configuration to defaults it starts works So I dont know where was the mistake but now It works thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my STS and it works fine. From your link:

*Check Automatically insert if you want the template to expand automatically on ctrl-space when there is no other matching template available. It is usually good idea to leave the checkbox checked, otherwise you would get a template proposal "popup".*

Under General - Keys "CTRL-SPACE" is bound to "Content Assist", do you have this also?